# Python : Finding an item in a list where a function return a minimum value?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've a list of point with coordinates and another point.

A sample from the list :

```
(45.1531912,5.7184742),(45.1531912,5.7184742),(45.1531113,5.7184544),(45.1525337,5.718298),(45.1525337,5.718298),
```

A point :

```
(45.1533837,5.7185242)
```

A function :

```
def dist(point1,point2)
   ....
   return aDistance
```

Is there a python one liner (list-comprehension ?) to find a point in the list where a given function returns the minimal value for the list ?

Comment: It should be helpful to provide some examples of your data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`min()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) takes a `key` argument already, no need for a list comprehension.

Let's say you wanted to find the closest point in the list to the origin:

```
min(list_of_points, key=lambda p: distance(p, (0, 0)))
```

would find it (given a `distance()` function that calculates the distance between two points).

From the documentation:

> The optional *key* argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`. The key argument, if supplied, must be in keyword form (for example, `min(a,b,c,key=func)`).