# PYTHON - Distance between closest pair in a list

Tags: python

How do you go about writing a function that analyzes a list or coordinate pairs, selects with pair is the closest using the distance formula, and then only returns that distance d.

Example input and output:

```
>>>function([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]])
>>>d
```

Comment: Read up on the [Closest Pair Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744237/python-finding-an-item-in-a-list-where-a-function-return-a-minimum-value/22744252#22744252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said the similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744237/python-finding-an-item-in-a-list-where-a-function-return-a-minimum-value/22744252#22744252). Here's the solution

```
a = [(5, 3), (9, 0), (4, 6), (2, 2), (0, 0)]

from math import sqrt


def function(a):
    distances = []
    def compute(fp, sp):
        return sqrt((fp[0]-sp[0])**2 + (fp[1] - sp[1])**2)

    for p in a:
        b = a[:]
        b.remove(p)
        distances.append(compute(p, min(b, key=lambda x: compute(x, p))))

    return min(distances)


print(function(a))
```

Output:
2.8284271247461903, that's equal to sqrt(8), because (2-0)<sup>2</sup>+(2-0)<sup>2</sup> == 8

Answer (score 1):

A simple brute force approach like the one shown on the Wikipedia article Sukrit links to, but with a small efficiency increase:

```
def min_dist(pair_list):
    n = len(pair_list)
    new_min_dist = float('inf')
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, n):
            new_x_dist = pair_list[i][0] - pair_list[j][0]
            new_y_dist = pair_list[i][1] - pair_list[j][1]
            new_min_dist = min(new_x_dist * new_x_dist + new_y_dist * new_y_dist, new_min_dist)
    return new_min_dist ** 0.5
```

There are a few efficiency additions here:

- Saving square root for the end so it's only used once (square root and exponentiation are expensive).
- Using `** 0.5` instead of `math.sqrt`, because for floats, exponentiation is faster than square root.
- Using multiplication instead of `** 2`, since exponentiation is much more expensive than multiplication.
- Only considering each pair once (Wikipedia's example also does this).
- `xrange` uses less memory, and doesn't have to allocate blocks, so it's slightly faster than `range`, provided there are fewer than about 32000 points. (Python 3 syntax will differ.)

Comment: The bruteforce approach is O(n^2) while the D&C approach is O(n*logn) and way cooler. ;) Nice answer though. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra Yeah, the D&C approach is way better for large numbers of pairs. Though, if you've got a pretty small number of points (< ~100), its overhead can exceed the savings. Another sneaky way to save processor time is to omit distance calculations if either x or y distances exceed the current minimum (since addition is cheaper than multiplication). D&C can be combined with the latter for maximal savings. O() time only counts the operations, so additional savings can often be found by exchanging expensive opps for cheap ones.

Comment: Okay. So that means I should first check if either `x_2 - x_1 > min_dist or y_2 - y_1 > min_dist` and if True, don't calculate the Euclidean distance for this set of pairs?

Comment: Indeed. Though since this Q&A is regarding python, I should point out that additional statements have their own overhead which might exceed the gains from pre-testing linear distance. In c, pre-testing x and y like this can be faster, provided that the results of `abs(x_2 - x_1)` and `abs(y_2 - y_1)` are kept for use in the distance calculation later, and that `abs()` is well-optimized.

Comment: Yes. Although the question is more about the Closest Pairs Algorithm. ;) Also, how would keeping the result of the two statements help? For when it's False and you can quickly square both and return their sum instead of recalculating the differences?

Comment: Basically yes, you avoid taking the difference multiple times. Even when used in a formula, like `(x - y) ** 2`, the `x - y` term is stored to a temporary variable which is calculated and then stored to a newly allocated memory location. In c, since you're close to the metal, you can get significant savings by re-using parts of the equation like that, since allocation will happen either way. (This is all not terribly relevant to the question, I know, but interesting IMHO.)

Comment: Yes. I, too, find things like these interesting. But, the regular college courses just go over the asymptotic analysis of these algorithms. Not on how to optimize these for programs. :)